# Nested classes serialization using Partial<>

Tags: typescript

I'd like to know if there's a (good) way to create nested classes in typescript from a json ?

I succeed to achieve it like this:

```
export class ImportEntity {
    public status: string;
    public Items: Item[];

   constructor(data: Partial<ImportEntity>) {
       Object.assign(this, data);
       this.mappingItems = [];

       if (data.Items)
           data.Items.forEach(item => { 
               this.Items.push(new Item(item));
           });
   }
}

export class Item {
    public column: string;
    public type: string;

    constructor(data: NestedPartial<MappingItem>) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}
```

but dealing manually with nested classes seems really weird (from a Java point of view :p )

Thanks.

Comment: looks like data.Items will be the same object as this.Items so you will be iterating and pushing into the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use the package serializer.ts ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/serializer.ts

from the doc :

```
import {Type} from "serializer.ts/Decorators";


    export class Album {

        id: number;

        name: string;

        @Type(() => Photo)
        photos: Photo[];
    }

    export class Photo {
        id: number;
        filename: string;
    }

    let album = deserialize<Album>(Album, albumJson);
```